# Using an overloaded operator+ within a function template in C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

This is for a school assignment. I am supposed to adhere to the requirement to use an overloaded operator and it has to be called within the function template called "increase".
This is a class called Inductor.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Inductor {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Inductor);

private:
    int inductance;
    double maxCurrent;

public: 
    int operator+(int add);
    int operator-(int sub);
    Inductor(int, double);
};

Inductor::Inductor(int x, double y)
{

    inductance = x;
    maxCurrent = y;
}


int Inductor::operator+(int add)
{
    int newSum = inductance + add;
    return newSum;
}

int Inductor::operator-(int sub)
{
    int newDiff = inductance - sub;
    return newDiff;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Inductor inductor)
{
    out << "Inductor parameters: " << inductor.inductance << ", " << inductor.maxCurrent << endl;
    return out;
}
```

While this is my function template "increase".

```
template<class FIRST>
FIRST increase(FIRST a, int b) {
    FIRST c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

Last but not least, my main file:

```
int main()
{
    Inductor ind(450, 0.5);
    ind = increase(ind, 70);
}
```

These are the following compilation errors which I do not understand:

```
error C2512: 'Inductor': no appropriate default constructor available
error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

note: could be 'Inductor &Inductor::operator =(Inductor &&)'
note: or       'Inductor &Inductor::operator =(const Inductor &)'
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'FIRST increase<Inductor>(FIRST,int)' being compiled
    with
    [
        FIRST=Inductor
    ]
note: see declaration of 'Inductor'
```

Can anyone care to explain why is the compiler throwing these errors? Yes I have googled and searched through StackOverflow, but I do not see an article where an overloaded operator+ from a class is being used within a function template.

Comment: Your addition operator returns an `int` but you assign the value to an `Inductor`, with no way to convert from `int` to `Inductor`.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class FIRST>
FIRST increase(FIRST a, int b) {
    FIRST c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

with `FIRST` == `Inductor` has several problems:

- `FIRST c;`: You try to create `Inductor` whereas there is no default constructor.
- `c = a + b;`: You try to assign to `Inductor` an `int` (return type of your `operator +`), and there is no such operator. and as there is no constructor taking only `int` to build `Inductor`, copy assignment is not an alternative.

The first error is easy to fix, just get rid of the variable (`return a + b;`) or initialize it directly (`FIRST c = a + b; return c;`).

For the second error, add a (non explicit) constructor taking only an `int` or change your `operator+` to return `Inductor` directly:

```
Inductor Inductor::operator+(int add)
{
    return Inductor(inductance + add, maxCurrent);
}
```

Comment: Is this what you meant for the second error , by changing operator+ to return Inductor directly?

Inductor Inductor::operator+(int add)
{
 Inductor ind = ind.inductance + add;
 return ind;
}
The compiler says there is no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "Inductor".
Is there any way I can fix the second error without creating a constructor, but merely changing how the items in operator+ works?